# "please enter a value" When all input fields are full

Tags: javascript

When I put a value into both boxes I still get the error "Please enter a value".  If I comment out the second If statement it works fine, just doesn't validate for the fields being left blank.  Not sure what's wrong with the if statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bmi.js"></script>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>

<body class="whole">
    <h2>BMI Calculator!</h2>
    <form>
        <section id="whinputs" class="inputs">
            <input id="weight" type="text" placeholder="Enter weight in pounds">
            <input id="height" type="text" placeholder="Enter height in inches">
        </section>

        <section class="buttons">
            <input type="button" onclick="valid()" value="Calculate BMI">
            <input type="reset">
        </section>
    </form>
    <h2 id="resultline"></h2>



</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var valid = function () {
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;


    if (isNaN(weight || height)) {
        return alert("Value must be a number!");
    }
    if (weight || height === "") {
        return alert("Please enter a value");
    }
    else {
        var result = ((weight / (Math.pow(height, 2))) * 703);
        var result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2)
        // return alert("Your BMI is " + result)
        return document.getElementById('resultline').innerHTML = ("Your BMI is " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code. One being the question you asked, and one you probably haven't noticed yet.

**The question you asked**

The problem lies in this code:

```
if (weight || height === "") {
    return alert("Please enter a value");
}
```

The code above translates into:

```
if [weight is a truthy value] OR [height is an empty string]
then return alert('Please enter a value');
```

But that's not what you really want. Instead, you should do it this way:

```
if (weight === '' || height === ''){
    return alert('Please enter a value');
}
```

Which translates to:

```
if [weight is an empty string] OR [height is an empty string]
then return alert('Please enter a value');
```

**The problem you probably haven't noticed yet**

```
if (isNaN(weight || height)) {
    return alert("Value must be a number!");
}
```

Which translates to:

```
if weight is a truthy value, then use isNaN(weight), else use isNaN(height)
then return alert('Value must be a number!');
```

But that's not what you really want. Instead, you should do it this way:

```
if (isNaN(weight) || isNaN(height)){
    return alert('Value must be a number!');
}
```

Which translates to:

```
if ( weight is NaN OR height is NaN )
then return alert('Value must be a number!');
```

**Test the code**

```js
var valid = function () {
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;

    /*
    if (isNaN(weight || height)) {
        return alert("Value must be a number!");
    }
    */
    if (isNaN(weight) || isNaN(height)){
        return alert('Value must be a number!');
    }
    
    /*
    if (weight || height === "") {
        return alert("Please enter a value");
    }
    */
    
    if (weight === '' || height === ''){
        return alert('Please enter a value');
    } else {
        var result = ((weight / (Math.pow(height, 2))) * 703);
        var result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2)
        // return alert("Your BMI is " + result)
        return document.getElementById('resultline').innerHTML = ("Your BMI is " + result);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bmi.js"></script>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>

<body class="whole">
    <h2>BMI Calculator!</h2>
    <form>
        <section id="whinputs" class="inputs">
            <input id="weight" type="text" placeholder="Enter weight in pounds">
            <input id="height" type="text" placeholder="Enter height in inches">
        </section>

        <section class="buttons">
            <input type="button" onclick="valid()" value="Calculate BMI">
            <input type="reset">
        </section>
    </form>
    <h2 id="resultline"></h2>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the logic with your if statement. Try this:

```
if ((weight === "") || (height === "")) {
    return alert("Please enter a value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the second if statement is wrong

```
if (weight || height === "")
```

will be true if weight has input
you want something like`if (isNaN(weight) || isNaN(height))`, if you want to make sure the input is number, you may also want to check whether it is divided by 0

Answer (score 0):

You were checking if weight was defined by leaving is the way it was.

```
if (isNaN(weight || height)) {
        return alert("Value must be a number!");
    }
    if (weight == "" || height == "") {
        return alert("Please enter a value");
    }
    else {
        var result = ((weight / (Math.pow(height, 2))) * 703);
         result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2)
        // return alert("Your BMI is " + result)
        document.getElementById('resultline').innerHTML = ("Your BMI is " + result);
```